# Delete duplicates in list structure (python)

Tags: python

I have the following structure in python:

```
revisions = [
['01.02.2010','abc','qwe'],
['02.02.2010','abc','qwe'],
['03.02.2010','aaa','qwe'],
['04.02.2010','aaa','qwe'],
['05.02.2010','aaa','qwe'],
['06.02.2010','aaa','dsa'],
]
```

how can i remove the duplicates with minimum algorithmic complexity? Output example:

```
 revisions = [
['01.02.2010','abc','qwe'],
['03.02.2010','aaa','qwe'],
['06.02.2010','aaa','dsa'],
```

]

EDIT: the list is already ordered by date.
EDIT2: Fixed example
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You try one of the solutions in the dozens of Related questions on the side.

Comment: I have been checking it once and I think that iteration was the simplest and least complex solution I found.

Comment: your example is syntactically incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A crude approach (while *guessing* what you're trying to do):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pprint

revisions = [
    ['01.02.2010','abc','qwe'],
    ['02.02.2010','abc','qwe'],
    ['03.02.2010','aaa','qwe'],
    ['04.02.2010','aaa','qwe'],
    ['05.02.2010','aaa','qwe'],
    ['06.02.2010','aaa','dsa'],
]

uniq, seen = [], set() # sets have O(1) membership tests

for rev in revisions:
    if tuple(rev[1:]) in seen:
        continue
    else:
        seen.add(tuple(rev[1:]))
        uniq.append(rev)

pprint.pprint(uniq)

# prints:
# [['01.02.2010', 'abc', 'qwe'],
#  ['03.02.2010', 'aaa', 'qwe'],
#  ['06.02.2010', 'aaa', 'dsa']]
```